# Discrete Math proof equations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

1. A
   stamp
   collector
   wants to
   include in her
   collection
   exactly
   one
   stamp
   from
   each
   country
   of
   Africa.
   If
   $I(s)$
   means
   that
   she
   has
   stamp
   s
   in
   her
   collection,
   $F
   (s,c)$
   means
   that
   stamp
   $s$
   was
   issued
   by
   country $c$,
   the
   domain
   for
   s
   is
   all
   stamps,
   and
   the
   domain
   for
   $c$
   is
   all
   countries
   of
   Africa,
   express
   the
   statement
   that
   her
   collection
   satisfies
   her
   requirement.
   Do
   not
   use
   the
   $\exists !$
   symbol.

2.Determine whether $(p\implies q) ∧ (¬p \implies q) ≡ q$

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: What have you tried? If you write an expression for #1, we may be able to help you modify it. For #2, must you prove the equivalence by using axioms or will a truth table be enough?

Comment: Please use titles for your questions that describe the contents of the questions themselves. What you picked as title applies to every single question in this site —all questions here are posted in order to ask others for help with them— so it provides absolutely no information whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

**I think you meant to say not to use the $\exists!$ symbol.**

As for $1.$ Let $A$ denote the set of all countries in Africa and $S$ denote the set of all stamps then the proposition below
$$\forall c\in A(\exists s_1\in S(I(s_1)\land F(s_1,c))\land \forall s_2\in S((I(s_2)\land F(s_2,c))\implies s_1 = s_2))$$
says that for every country $c$ in Africa there is a stamp $s_1$ in the stamp collectors collection that was issued by country $c$ and given any stamp $s_2$ in her collection that was issued by country $c$ the stamp $s_2$ must be the same as $s_1$

In short it is a claim about existence and uniqueness.

and as for $2.$ You are required to prove that $(p \implies q)\land(\neg p\implies q)$  and $q$ imply each other.

First assume that $(p \implies q)\land(\neg p\implies q)$ is true moreover we know that $p\lor \neg p$ is a tautology and in both instances when $p$ is true or false we can use our assumption in conjunction with *modus ponens* to deduce $q$.

For the converse notice that $p\implies q$ and $\neg p\implies q$ can be written as 
$\neg p\lor q$ and $p\lor q$ respectively so if you assume $q$ to be true the result follows naturally.

Hope that helps

Comment: I didnt know that there were different symbol lol thanks. As for the second question, im not sure what you did.